# Cannot resolve symbol MediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener

Tags: android

I am a beginner, just started android. I am trying to do something on my sound completion. So i have called a setOnCompletionListener by MediaPlayer object. But error occurs saying cannot resolve symbol setOnCompletionListener.
Please do help me to sort out this problem.

**Here, is Code Package**

```
package com.example.jay_mainframe.justjava;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Button btn;
    boolean flag=true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.birthday);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play_btn);

    }

    public void playMusic(View view){
        if (flag) {
            mp.start();
            btn.setText("Pause Me");
            flag=false;
        }
        else {
            mp.pause();
            btn.setText("Play me");
            flag = true;
        }

    }

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //Do the work after completion of audio
        }
    });

}
```

`

Comment: You have a standard Java compilation error, it has little to nothing to do with Android

Answer (score 1):

Wrong scope.
The code:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Do the work after completion of audio
    }
});
```

Should be inside `onCreate` method. Or just inside a function, not inside class.